# BitmapImage WriteableBitmap in windows store - metro

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

How do I convert a  BitmapImage to WriteableBitmap  Object in metro applications?
i've been searching for a while but i got no where 
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, it is really hard to do without third party libraries.
Still, you can create **WritableBitmap** from **StorageFile**.

```
public static async Task<WriteableBitmap> writableImageFromFile(StorageFile file)
{
    IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

    WriteableBitmap writableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
    writableBitmap.SetSource(fileStream);

    return writableBitmap;
}
```

Don't forget this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
```